# How to use a library made in Delphi in an asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, delphi, integration, delphi-10-seattle

One asp.net application I am writing must serve a pdf file and an drawing (dxf AutoCAD file) both created with a Delphi program.

Just to clarify the scenario: I have skilled Delphi developers so I assigned them the task to create the programs who create the pdf and the dxf file.

So there is a total of 3 systems:

1) an asp.net Main application

2) a Delphi application which recieves some parameters (from asp.net) and genreates a pdf file.

3) a Delphi application which recieves some parameters (from asp.net) and genreates a dxf file.

Now the Delphi applications as standalone win32 applications (in which the parmeters are set through UI controls) work both fine and i need to convert them so that they can be used from asp.net.

I am not interested in concurrency/performance issues, my goal is just to call the "part of the system that creates a file" so that I can let the enduser of the asp.net application download it. I can also accept that this is out of threads (I mean: only one user can call in background one of the Delphi applciations at a time)

Could you please suggest the best approach for this?

Before starting this proejct I had in mind "dll" or "command line exe" but now i am in doubt and wonder that may be i am missing some more convenient technique.

Please consider that porting to c# the libraries it is not an option since we used some 3rd party Delphi components that have no a 100% .net counterpart.

Comment: i do not understand the negative vote. Please explain it with a comment. I googled a lot before asking.

Comment: I'd guess your question is too broad, since you're actually asking for suggestions (*Could you please suggest...*). It's like coming here and asking "How can I integrate with Google Maps API". Even though you googled a lot, you haven't posted what you've tried so far, didn't show a code sample.

Comment: Anyway, if I was to answer it, I'd *suggest* your C# app to create a **.txt** or **.xml** containing the parameters in some folder, the Delphi app would have a mechanism (like a `Timer`) to eventually scan that folder and process the request, C# app would wait until the **pdf** was avaible in another (or the same) folder. You might want to create another folder for your other type of request. Also, I'd try to create these Delphi apps as **windows services**, it looks they actually doesn't need an UI.

Comment: It's way too broad and opinion based. Sorry, not a fit for this site

Comment: @Alisson the solution you suggested with `TTimer` and a text file is smart and i can consider it too. In simple cases like this one I  use NSSM to quickly convert a standalone exe into a Windows Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Years ago (around the Delphi 8 timeframe), there was an actual Delphi.NET compiler that could produce .NET assemblies that run in ASP.NET ([my own website](http://www.lebeausoftware.org) still runs today on some ASP.NET assemblies I wrote with Delphi.NET), and even use [Delphi as a scripting language in ASP.NET coding](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28974).  But Delphi.NET is now a dead product and .NET is no longer a supported platform by any modern Delphi compiler.

So, if you want to run Delphi code in ASP.NET, you are going to have to either:

1. Write a plain DLL and install it into your site's `\bin` folder, and then access it using PInvoke.
2. Write a COM object and install it on the server machine, and then access it using COM interop (see the `Server.CreateObject()` method).
3. port your code to another compiler that supports native .NET development.

Comment: You can expose the code as a COM object. Or expose it as a Win32 dll and consume it using pinvoke. This answer is thus factually incorrect.

Comment: Thank you. Pinovke sounds good. Another smart solution is to use the standalone exe (with timer approach described in the comments of the question) installed with NSSM

Comment: I suggested the timer approach because it was the simplest solution I could think. If I was to use the suggestions given by @RemyLebeau I'd have to do some reasearch, since I'm a newbie when it comes to COM and generating .net compatible dlls. If you have time to do researches (or already know how to do it), I think it would be a good idea following Remy's suggestion.

Comment: I do not have time for research, deadline pressure so timer is fine, moreover there is a database so instead of a file I will use a db table as communication toolm